# I'm trying to post form data using axios and I'm facing an error "Network Error" and response is "Unrecongnized FormData part"

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, react-redux, axios

I'm trying to post data using `Axios`.When I try to call `action`, I got an **error** and my request gone failed.The `response` I get is `Unrecognized FormData part`.I've attached the screenshots of my code.Kindly help in my to slove this issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As for the next time, copy and paste your code in the question. It's easier for us to copy your code from text than from a screenshot...

Comment: You need to check, was your formdata correctly sent . You can do it in network tab of chrome dev tools. Could you attach  info about your request from there.

Comment: If there is still error, you can try to remove  params, that you append one by one, and check. Maybe there is problem with one of your params . Also be aware, that in .append() with two parameters  second will be converted to  USVString. If you want to add file, you need to pass third argument. Also all of your objects, that you tries to append will be converted to strings like '[object Object]', so you need to convert them to JSON manually.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append